# How can I know what happened to each SQL statement given in execute()?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
try
{
   Statement  stmt=con1.createStatement();
   String multiqueryString="Update table1 set name='';Select * fromaww table1; "

   boolean hasMoreResultSets = stmt.execute( multiQuerySqlString );
}
```

As you can see first statement is correct, but the second is incorrect (near `from`).
But an update will be executed then Java will find error in second statement and give me error instead of  separately telling about what happened to each statement.

How can I get update message and error message separately?

Comment: You stop executing several SQL queries at once. As far as I know, only MySQL allows that anyway (if MySQL can choose to do something stupid, it generally will).

Comment: but I am taking sql queries as input from textarea I have to take multiple queries.

Comment: Is there any way to do that?? @JB Nizet

Comment: Search for allowMultiQueries in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html. Notice that by default, it's false. Which is a good thing, since that is normally not supported by JDBC, and a really bad idea. So, either tell your users that only a single query is allowed, or split the entered text into multiple queries (but that isn't such an easy task without a SQL parser).

Comment: How can I bulid a SQL Parser ?? Or should I separate the  sql statements  (like by semicolon ).But that would be problematic when delimiter is changed in making trigger?? @JBNizet

Comment: please help @JBNizet Sir . Nobody is even  able to understand this

Comment: I told you: either let the driver throw an exception when the user tries entering several queries (which it should do), or write or find a SQL parser that allows splitting the entered text into multiple queries, and execute each query separately.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much Sir you made my day :)